# Get a SQLite row based on title and date

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get a single row based on title and date.
I have created some code, but i it correct? What are all the null-fields in the code?

```
public Cursor getRecordFromMondayByTitleDate(String inpRowTitle, String inpRowDate) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_MONDAY, new String[] {KEY_M_ROWID, KEY_M_TITLE, KEY_M_DATE,
                    KEY_M_WEIGHT, KEY_M_SET_A, KEY_M_SET_B, 
                    KEY_M_SET_C, KEY_M_SET_D}, 
                    KEY_M_TITLE + "= '" + inpRowTitle + "'", 
                    null,
                    KEY_M_DATE + "= '" + inpRowDate + "'", 
                     null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

My database table DATABASE_TABLE_MONDAY layout is the following:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE_MONDAY =
    "create table if not exists " + DATABASE_TABLE_MONDAY + " (m_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "m_title VARCHAR not null, m_date date, m_weight DOUBLE, m_set_a INT, m_set_b INT, m_set_c INT, m_set_d INT);";
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your query should look more like this:

```
db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_MONDAY, 
    new String[] {KEY_M_ROWID, KEY_M_TITLE, KEY_M_DATE, KEY_M_WEIGHT, KEY_M_SET_A, KEY_M_SET_B, KEY_M_SET_C, KEY_M_SET_D},
    KEY_M_TITLE + "='" + inpRowTitle + "' AND " + KEY_M_DATE + "='" + inpRowDate + "'",
    null,
    null, 
    null,
    null);
```

Your *table* and *columns* parameters were correct. The third parameter, the *selection* parameter, is essentially the WHERE clause from SQL, so you want both your title and date specified here. The fourth parameter is *selectionArgs*, and is there to "help" with coding the *selection*. If you specify a *selection* with question marks, the question marks are replaced, in order, with the values in the array you provide. Using  *selectionArgs* is not necessary, and you can pass null if your *selection* is written in full. After that, the parameters specify how you want the query returned to you, and all may be passed a `null` value. The fifth is *groupBy*, and corresponds to the SQL clause GROUP BY. The sixth corresponds to HAVING, the seventh to ORDER BY. The last parameter is *limit*, and just puts a cap on how many records a query returns. If you don't need to limit your query, you can just omit this parameter, as there is a `query()` method without *limit*. If you're unfamiliar with SQL, you may want to do a little studying to know what each of those clauses does for your query.

Comment: Both queries gave me a error message, but by altering the query to the following I got it working!
[code]
          db.query(DATABASE_TABLE_MONDAY, 
               new String[] {KEY_M_ROWID, KEY_M_TITLE, KEY_M_DATE, KEY_M_WEIGHT, KEY_M_SET_A, KEY_M_SET_B, KEY_M_SET_C, KEY_M_SET_D},
               KEY_M_TITLE + "='" + inpRowTitle + "' AND " + KEY_M_DATE + "='" + inpRowDate + "'",
               
               null, 
               null,
               null,
               null);
[/code]